# determine if attribute has been serialized rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm have a rails 3.2 app that has a class with:

```
class Element
  serialize :body
end
```

In the code how do I inspect the attribute to determine if the field is just text or is serialized?  Then if serialized I need to know if it has

```
  serialize :body
  # vs
  serialize :body, Hash
  # vs
  serialize :body, Array
```

NOTE:  I need to go from `Element.new` to an object with the correct type.  I'm not just grabbing this object from the DB.  Doing `Element.new` the field will be `nil`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you start with `serialized_attributes`

then if that field has a serialized field it will be in a hash and hence respond to `object_class`.  COOL

```
(dev)> Element.serialized_attributes
  => {"value"=>#<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007ffcb30a9f08 @object_class=Object>, "body"=>#<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007ffcb3096818 @object_class=Object>}

(dev)> Element.serialized_attributes['value']
  => #<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007ffcb3213010 @object_class=Array>
(dev)> Element.serialized_attributes['value'].try(:object_class)
  => Array
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that `serialized_attributes` has been removed from ActiveRecord. The closest I've found in Rails 5+ is `attributes_before_type_cast`, and  `read_attribute_for_serialization`

Comment: With (at least) rails 7 you can use `attributes_to_define_after_schema_loads`

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.0 and later to get the same result as `#serialized_attributes` from earlier Rails you can do:

```
Element.attribute_types.select { |_k, v| v.respond_to?(:coder) }
=> {"value"=>#<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007ffcb30a9f08 @object_class=Object>,
    "body"=>#<ActiveRecord::Coders::YAMLColumn:0x007ffcb3096818 @object_class=Object>}
```